# Wordpress plugin for mail subscriptions

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, plugin-recommendation, subscription, email

I'm working on a news site built with Wordpress, and I now want to add a page for subscriptions. This will be paid subscriptions for the **printed paper that people can get delivered to their home**.

My question is: is there a Wordpress plugin already created for this (free or paid)? I wouldn't really want to re-invent the wheel. Maybe I could somehow use one of the many Wordpress shopping cart solutions?

If not (which I suspect to be the case) how would I go about doing it on my own? I have no problem coding this up as a standalone application. I'm just not sure of how exactly to integrate it into the Wordpress admin area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/s2member/

Comment: An answer should be [more than a link to an external site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion).

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use a premium plugin like this http://member.wishlistproducts.com/

I can add that, as you point out, this can work seamlessy with the WooCommerce solution. There is WooCommerce plugin to http://www.woothemes.com/extension/wishlist-member-integration/ for this.

So, WooCommerce (free), WishList Member (97$ single licence), WooCommerce WishList Member Plugin (35$) would do the job.

Comment: I'm a little confused: I'm not simply selling a membership service to the site, but a paid subscription to a **physical paper home delivery**. The price will vary upon the location it is being delivered to, the shipping method, as well as on the subscription type (monthly prepaid, monthly pay-as-you-go, upfront payment for 1/2 years etc.). How will a WishList Member Plugin help me?

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe the WishList Member Plugin is an overkill for your need. I just think that a merge between the two would allow you to solve all your need: woocommerce for location delivery and shipping method, WishList Member for subscription type and duration. You have 30 days free test use. Ah, I'm not working for any of them :)

Answer (score 0):

I have done exactly that process with another site, that was originally a static website, which we then migrated to Wordpress.

Take a look at 1shoppingcart.com

It may be a good (if not alternative) solution for you. Some features: Auto-responders, can handle the different payment options and durations and as its not maintaining access to any WP pages, you simply use links from the posts to integrate with it.

Hope that helps